What is the reason that the unstable Lagrange point $L_2$ is used for the JWST instead of the stable $L_4$ or $L_5$ points?

I understand how the Lagrange points work in the two-body problem.  I can do that math.  I understand that for L1, L2, or L3, if the object is perturbed to deviate away from that point, the combination of gravity and orbital mechanics will not bring the object back, it will drift further away. It's like an object resting on the summit of a peak or of a ridge of a mountain.
But the L4 and L5 Lagrange points are stable.  A perturbed object there will drift back to the L4 or L5 point if it were to be perturbed by a small amount.  It's like an object resting in a small depression in the vicinity of the mountain.
So the JWST needs some fuel and propellant (perhaps a very small amount) to remain at its L2 point.  Why was this point chosen?  How long is the fuel/propellant in the JWST expected to last?  (I would think it would need to be several decades, considering how valuable this asset is.)
Is it because the shadow of the Earth removes some of the light from the Sun?  (But it doesn't get all of it, hence the heat shield.)
Is it because the L4 and L5 points may have, over the last 4.5 billion years, accumulated some space dust or debris?  Crap from asteroids and comets and such?  I would expect no such dust/debris to accumulate at the L1, L2, or L3 points.  Any such stuff would drift further and further away from the Lagrange point.
Those are the only two reasons that I can think of, and I am not sure how valid those speculations are.
Is the halo orbit at L2 actually stable?  I cannot expect that.  In fact, I might expect that the halo orbit, around any of L1, L2, L3, will expand slowly.
Also, since the JWST is positioned at the Sun-Earth L2, does the monthly movement of the moon perturb the position of the JWST that needs to be compensated for?  Because the moon is reasonably massive, in comparison to the Earth, it would seem to me to really toss a wrench into this L2 halo orbit that would require a lotta fuel to fix.

Yeah, that diagram is okay for reference, but very much not to scale.  It makes it appear that L2 and L4 are not that different in distance.

The distance from the JWST to the SEMB L2 varies between (roughly) 450,000 km & 850,000 km. I have various plots here https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49616/16685 & https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57832/38535 including interactive 3D orbits.

An overview report by the NGST study team (Stockman, 1997) does not discuss the Trojan orbit, but it discusses a couple of orbits at similar distances, and the primary difficulty cited is communication. L4 is 100 times as far away from earth as L2. That means any signals from the telescope would be 10,000 times weaker, requiring a much more powerful transmitter (or a different communication modality) to deliver a similar bit rate, and a 100 times longer time delay, making real-time communication much more difficult.
Nevertheless, more distant orbital positions were seriously considered. Table 9.2 in the report (p. 113) summarizes the tradeoffs considered when they made their recommendation to place the telescope at L2.


This location is perfect for Webb's sunshield to block out light and
heat from the Sun, Earth, and Moon. Unlike the Hubble Space Telescope,
Webb's orbit keeps the spacecraft out of the Earth's shadow making L2
a thermally stable location for the observatory to operate at.

Source

As an addendum to other (correct) answers, the question of fuel longevity that you ask about has also been discussed, as in here. In summary, the JWST did launch with onboard hydrazine for attitude control/stationkeeping, and while it was originally intended to retain enough fuel to sustain its station at L2 for ten years, the precision of the Ariane launch and the midcourse correction are frequently credited with allowing it to keep enough fuel to last for twenty years instead.
This is assuming that we don't ever go up for repairs/refuels/upgrades, which we probably won't - we can do that for telescopes like the Hubble because they're in low orbit which is much more easy to access for maintaining satellites than L2 where the JWST and other satellites like Euclid and Gaia are.

Any kind of maintenance / refuelling of the JWST would be tricky, but not impossible. See https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56205/38535 & https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38389/38535

There you go - if we really really care, we can keep it up there. It's more difficult than LEO maintenance but yeah it's not impossible.

I expect that it would be quite hard for a robotic service craft to match orbits with the JWST without damaging it. But if we do refuel it, it would also be nice if we could recharge the helium in its cooling system. It uses a closed cycle cryocooler, but of course helium gradually leaks out. I don't know if the cryocooler has a recharge port, but there's some info about the cryocooler at https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58825/38535 & https://space.stackexchange.com/a/60209/38535

That's the other thing, I'm not sure the JWST's hydrazine/helium tanks are actually capable of being refilled because it was intended to be expendable (which really sucks given how cool it is). Worst case scenario, if we really care, we can wait for it to drift out to L3 or L4 and then go there which might be a bit easier to rendezvous with when it's partly illuminated.

The accepted answer at the 2nd link says "at least there is a valve for filling up the propellant tanks."

In that case, they can refuel the propellant tanks. Yay! Today I learned.

Correction: Gaia is at $L_2$, not low Earth orbit.

Whoops, yep. Sorry bout that.

Okay, to press another question, how is it that the L2 point supports orbital motion?  Objects are not attracted to the L2 point as they are to the L4 or L5 points. Why doesn't the orbiting JWST just (slowly) spiral away from the L2 point?  In fact, why is there any curvature inward at all?  Why doesn't the JWST just make a bee-line away from L2?

It would if not for its propulsion system. It’s true that L2 doesn’t attract; the JWST, in order to “orbit” around L2, has an onboard propulsion system that lets it periodically make small adjustments to its trajectory to keep itself roughly where it is. You ask a very good question, since L2 is a hard place to keep a satellite; it does in fact take a lot of fuel to keep satellites there (much more than station keeping in LEO or GSO).
